# Visual Studio Code Chrome Debugger Extension - [webkit-debug-adapter] Got response from target app, but no valid target pages found

Tags: angularjs, typescript, remote-debugging, visual-studio-code

I Have an Angular/TypeScript app. I can debug the TypeScript in Chrome because I use map files.

Today I installed Debugger for Chrome from Visual Studio Marketplace. 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome

In theory I should be able to set break points in vscode but I keep getting this error when I run the debugger:

[webkit-debug-adapter] Got response from target app, but no valid target pages found

The reason for this is because I do not know how to set it up properly.

I have my app running on port 9000 using Grunt. Here is the debugger config file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9000,
        "webRoot": "./app/scripts"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know how to attach the debugger?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed to get this working myself. For anyone else who comes across this problem, here is the config file.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:9000/",//Change to whatever you homepage is
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--new-window", //Open in new window
            "--user-data-dir=C:/dev/", //Can be any directory. Makes chrome load in a different directory so that it opens in a new instance.
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222" //Open in port 9222 (standard chrome debug port)
        ],
        "webRoot": "src/app/", //The directory that contains js, ts and map files
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Verified this technique works in Angular2 Beta with TypeScript. Dude... You're awesome. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Hi! Thanks to your tips I can launch chrome from Code, but breakpoints are never hit. I have .js and .map files in same folder (wwwroot/app), and I have the ts files under Scripts (same level as wwwroot). Do you know if this can be an issue? I have set gulp-sourcemap sourceRoot to "../scripts" and in launch.json I have set webRoot to ${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot. Tried many combinations without any luck. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with angular-cli with following launch.json

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/", //your application running with ng serve
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--new-window", //Open in new window
                "--user-data-dir=remote-profile",
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222" //Open in port 9222 (standard chrome debug port)
            ],
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: when attaching start chrome with following arguments C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-profile

Answer (score 0):

From the [readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)

> If Code can't find the target, you can always verify that it is actually available by navigating to http://localhost:< port >/json in a browser. If you get a response with a bunch of JSON, and can find your target page in that JSON, then the target should be available to this extension.

I'm guessing you are getting a `Cannot GET /json` but how to fix that i have no idea.

Comment: Can you explain why Chrome serves my test app through http://localhost:8080/index.html, but requesting http://localhost:8080/json displays the "Cannot GET /json" message. How can I make my testapp visible to the debug adapter?